# How to start the lifecycle of a component when using noop zone?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use noop zone in my Angular application, but when I route to a component, it is not initialized. The constructor is called, but the lifecycle is not started and ngOnInit is not called.

Here is an application (with zone.js enabled) in which my AppComponent has a router-outlet. We are directly routed to the HelloComponent component, and it initializes correctly : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hlcf5g

Now, here is the same app but I use `{ ngZone: 'noop' }` in main.ts : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pseswv

{{title}} is not working an ngOnInit is not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is a normal behavior when your zone is "nooped". Angular creates an instance of the `NoopNgZone` class which does nothing. Nooped zone requires explicit calls to framework to perform rendering. This looks as follows:

```js
function getNgZone(ngZoneOption?: NgZone | 'zone.js' | 'noop'): NgZone {
  let ngZone: NgZone;

  if (ngZoneOption === 'noop') {
    ngZone = new NoopNgZone();
  } else {
    ngZone =
      (ngZoneOption === 'zone.js' ? undefined : ngZoneOption) ||
      new NgZone({ enableLongStackTrace: isDevMode() });
  }
  return ngZone;
}
```

If the zone is not "nooped" - Angular monitors microtask queue (thanks zone.js), and gets notified when there is no more microtasks enqueued in the current VM Turn. This is a hint for Angular to do change detection, thus Angular invokes `ApplicationRef.prototype.tick()` under the hood for you.

You have to call `tick` manually, it's a synchronous process and you have to do it after Angular has done its internal initializations or any job.

You can use `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame`, I would prefer `requestAnimationFrame` as the new Angular's rendering engine `Ivy` uses `requestAnimationFrame` under the hood to schedule change detection.

Look at the below code and try it out in the stackblitz that you've provided:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello',
  template: 'Title : <h1>{{title}}</h1>'
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Hello';

  constructor(app: ApplicationRef) {
    console.log('constructor');
    requestAnimationFrame(() => app.tick());
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
  }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend you to use "nooped" zone as you will to run change detection manually everywhere, look at the example below:

```html
<button (click)="increment()">{{ counter }}</button>
```

Our `counter` property of the component class will be incremented, for sure, but it won't be updated in the DOM, so you will also have to run `tick()`:

```js
increment() {
  this.counter++;
  this.app.tick();
}
```

You will also need to call a `ChangeDetectorRef.prototype.markForCheck()` function, if your component is marked with `OnPush` strategy, for example in that case `title` will not be updated:

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ApplicationRef,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello',
  template: 'Title : <h1>{{title}}</h1>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Hello';

  constructor(app: ApplicationRef) {
    console.log('constructor');
    requestAnimationFrame(() => app.tick());

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.title = 'Another title';
      app.tick();
    }, 2000);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
  }
}
```

But this will:

```js
constructor(app: ApplicationRef, ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  console.log('constructor');
  requestAnimationFrame(() => app.tick());

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.title = 'Another title';
    ref.markForCheck();
    app.tick();
  }, 2000);
}
```

As Angular checks under the hood if the component is marked with `OnPush` strategy via:

```js
if (view.def.flags & ViewFlags.OnPush)
```

And changes view's state to the `ChecksEnabled`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a handler for router-outlet activate event and call tick method there. This will help call the ngOnInit of the component rendered by the router.

Inside app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private ref: ApplicationRef) {

  }
  routeActivated() {
    this.ref.tick();
    console.log('ref ticked');
  }
}
```

Inside app.component.html

```html
<div>App Component</div>
<router-outlet (activate)="routeActivated()"></router-outlet>
```